# generic compilation time option in fortran

Tags: makefile, fortran, compiler-optimization

the compilation options are vendor specific (in my knowledge)
so, in makefile, I have to provide,

```
if FC=ifort
 FFLAGS=<long list of options provided by intel>
else 
if FC=gfortran
 FFLAGS=<same list in gnu way>
end if
```

is there a way to specify a generic option? by generic, I mean, a vendor
independent way of specifying the options. I don't mind creating them
using `autotools(i.e. autoconf, automake)`. but is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, if this answers your question or provides you any help at all. But, what I use to allow activation of compiler options in a more generic way, is to define variables for specific features, for example warning, debugging, optimization and profiling, and set these according to the compiler currently used.

I am using waf for configuration and building, see for example this [build script](https://bitbucket.org/apesteam/aotus/src/2a1b1f062087c8279e1e5b210fdde7a23899035b/wscript?at=default), where the FCFLAGS are set according to the configured compiler, with different options activated for the various build variants, that are available. I guess, you can do something similar with autotools, or pure make.